# phonegap -- read and play audio from the device's media library?

Tags: android, ios, audio, cordova

I haven't used phonegap before but I'm considering it for a project which needs to be able to play audio from the device's media library -- is that possible? Does it require a plugin? The examples I've seen seem to have the audio files as assets of the app or stream them with http.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap does have a [Media API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media), but you'll probably need to write your own plugin for accessing the device's media library...

Hope this helps